# retrieve data from temporary table to main table

Tags: sql, oracle

So I need to count average time from start to end, the thing is I only have `end` column at temporary table, so the row at temporary table will be moved to main table at the of session.

My question is, how can I retrieve `end` column from temporary table to main table (or any table) without lose the data?

My tables look something like this;

```
TEMPORARY TABLE

start | end | subject | body 
10:30 | 10:40 | receipt | bla bla bla
11:23 | 11:34 | receipt confirmation | bla bla bla

MAIN TABLE

start | subject | body
10:30 | receipt | bla bla bla
11:23 | receipt confirmation | bla bla bla
```

Comment: Very much unclear question!! Can you please share the sample data and expected output? And also what you have tried?

Comment: updated! thanks Tejash

Answer (score 0):

**You can write like this:**

```
Select
 main.start,
 temp.end,
 main.subject,
 main.body
from main
left/inner join temp on main.id=temp.id and your_other_conditions
```

Comment: I have tried that, but the thing is, every time the session end, the `end` column will be disappeared. so I can't do that

Comment: @rfzio . . . Your comment doesn't make sense.  This answers the question that you have asked.  If you have other issues not included in this question, then ask a *new* question.